# rxjava interval combined with another observable

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

I have an observable (that is hot) that is doing things via system process, and I'd like to have an interval also running, until the process observable hits onComplete.

I see the interval operator: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html

How can I combine these two to get he behavior I want (in particular, cancel the interval when the other hits onComplete)?

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 1):

You can use `takeUntil()` operator in order to cancel (unsubscribe) the interval operator, `takeUntil()` takes `Observable` as input, and cancel when input `Observable` emits an item.

What it's left is to transform the hot `Observable` to an `Observable` that emit an item with its `onComplete()`, so we can use it as input to `takeUntil()`, this is possible using `materialize()` operator, that emit `Notification` object for each `Observable` event (`onNext()`, `onError()`, `onCompleted()`), in conjunction with `filter()` to take only `onCompleted()` events.

```
Observable<Notification<Object>> hotOnCompleteObservable = 
            hot.materialize()
               .filter(notification -> notification.isOnCompleted());

Observable interval = ...
interval.takeUntil(hotOnCompleteObservable);
```